# How can i code in latex for multiple figures and in two rows with same caption?

Tags: floats, subcaption

[image]

Here in this I want to upload a figure in latex with a format that I showed by an image.. please help

Comment: `\begin{figure}\centering\includegraphics{} \includegraphics{} \includegraphics{} \includegraphics{}\caption{zzzz}\end{figure}` should work

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yeah it's working somehow, thanx for that, but I want to add some caption to with every figure

Comment: I assumed from your question "with same caption" that you meant you wanted a single caption for all four images.

Comment: @hema, any news?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

With small effort for searching for similar questions you would find that your question is actually duplicate to some already existed ... anyway, a MWE which had produce above image is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
    \caption{}
\label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
\label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}

    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{}
\label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}{0.45\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{}
\label{fig:1a}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{My composed figure}
    \label{fig:1}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```