# using float package, I want to have multiple images in one figure, but the position of the figure in the output is wrong

Tags: biblatex

Im using [This answer for subfigures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367204/278494) on StackExchange but when I use it in my paper documentation the figure appears in the refrence section!

Comment: well `figure`  is a float environment, and floats have a tendency to float. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2388

Comment: Please show a minimal reproducible example. Which class do you use? Does it have a floating mechanism? If yes, you need to add a floating specifier like `\begin{figure}[htbp]` to the code from the answer

Comment: (Can you please also edit your title to one which describes the problem you have? This will help future users with the same problem to find your post)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks \begin{figure}[H] fixed my problem.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you. using your comment and changing htbp to H i mean \begin{figure}[H] the problem has gone. thanks

Comment: @AmirrezaHashemi `[H]` will usually result in a suboptimal result. With `[htbp]` you give latex more freedom to find a good place for your figure.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz but `htbp` did not work for me at all!

Comment: If `[htbp]` does not work it means that the position you want the image to be in might not be a good position. Maybe the figure is too big, maybe there isn't enough space on that page... without having a minimal reproducible example it's hard to tell.